# Why does android images use bitmaps to display?

Tags: android, bitmap

Aren't bitmaps incredibly large and inefficient?

How come Android image views uses them then?

```
Uri new_picture_uri = data.getData();

try
{
    Bitmap new_picture_bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), new_picture_uri);

    DISPLAY_VIEW.setImageBitmap(new_picture_bmp);
}
catch (IOException exception)
{
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitmaps are inefficient storage wise but perfect display wise. Android converts more space efficient formats (png, jpg, etc) into bitmap objects to manipulate and display.